# How to turn off html5 browser tool-tip validation messages?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to turn off the default hover text but keep the hover text that is shown in the black box. We are using Tipsy here and want to continue to use this on our pages.

I am using HTML5 in a web form to help with validation and want to keep validation turned on so I don't have to write a lot of JavaScript code. I don't want to add the non-validate to form.

The double hover text is not only confusing to the users but doesn't look the greatest either.

Please see the attached picture below.

[image]

Thanks for all of you suggestions, but maybe my initial post was not clear.

- This is my issue:
  I want to remove all default tool-tip messages that the Browser is displaying when the html5 input control is either empty or becomes invalid, such as shown in the picture shown above. I want to avoid showing double tool-tips.

html5 Example:

I have tried adding the oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Testing')" - but this is not really what I want either since the invalid only gets called when posting the form and also the default browser tool-tip still will remain.

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Do not have a real solution to test, but this should be a TITLE property of element. Just delete the property title="" and everything should be fine. If the used forms are too complex to get through code manually, you can use Jquery...

```
$('#id_of_an_element').find('*').removeAttr('title');
```

Comment: Setting the title property for the element will not work since the browser (mine happens to be Chrome)  is what is showing the hover text. I want to be able to just turns this functionality off and not show any browser interrupted hover text since I am using Tipsy for the custom validation text as shown in my picture. This is a HTML5 feature that I want to disable.

Comment: have you actually tried it? see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/or9aoymh/